# Update phpmyadmin manually when installed as an package

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, php

Is it possible to manually update phpMyAdmin when I installed it as a package?
The current version in Ubuntus package list is 3.4.5deb1 but I want to upgrade to 3.4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package manager offers whatever version is in the release of Ubuntu that you have installed. If you want a more recent version that what your release has, look for a [PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_PPAs), a third-party package archive. PPAs are [hosted on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas). There is one PPA which has [recent versions of PhpMyAdmin](https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/phpmyadmin).

Comment: How safe is it to add other PPA like this?

Comment: @Patrik Most PPAs only provide a single program. Anyone can upload a PPA; it's up to you to decide whether you trust the person who provides it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the current version of software won't be available via your package manager because the community hasn't gotten around to packaging it yet. Therefore the latest version you can get through `apt` is probably `3.4.5`.

You have two options. Either you can wait for the community to package version `3.4.8` for you and add it to the repositories (or package it yourself). Or you can remove phpMyAdmin using `apt` and install it from source. Installing it from source gives you the option of upgrading whenever you want right from the developer.

Comment: Do you know how often do these things get updated?

Comment: @Patrik A new release of Ubuntu is made every 6 months. Programs are never updated during a release's lifetime.